# Rustlings not installing due to experimental features

Tags: rust

I'm trying to install rustlings via curl, but I'm running into the issue:

```
error[E0658]: non exhaustive is an experimental feature
 --> /home/me/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/console-0.14.0/src/kb.rs:5:1
  |
5 | #[non_exhaustive]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44109
  = help: add #![feature(non_exhaustive)] to the crate attributes to enable

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: failed to compile `rustlings v4.3.0 (/home/me/Desktop/rust/rustlings)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/home/me/Desktop/rust/rustlings/target`

Caused by:
  Could not compile `console`.
```

The installer redirects me to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44109, which doesn't help. I'm running rustc 1.37.0-nightly (0af8e872e 2019-06-30) and trying to install rustlings 4.3.0

Does anybody know how I can fix this error?

Comment: You are trying to install latest release of rustlings using a quite old version of compiler. This experimental feature has since been stabilised. Update your toolchain to a current version (1.49, at the moment).

Comment: `#[non_exhaustive]` was stabilized in [Rust 1.40](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/12/19/Rust-1.40.0.html#non_exhaustive-structs-enums-and-variants) (nearly a year ago)

Comment: For some reason `rustup update` doesn't install the newest version of rustc. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Non exhaustive structs and enums were stabilized [in Rust 1.40](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/12/19/Rust-1.40.0.html#non_exhaustive-structs-enums-and-variants). You are running Rust 1.37, an older version of the compiler. Updating your toolchain to a newer version will fix the issue:

```sh
$ rustup update
```

Comment: I've run the command which updates rustc, but the issue persists.

Comment: Running the update didn't actually update rustc.